# Galois group of residue field over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Assume $L$ is a number field and is Galois over $\mathbb Q$,$\mathcal O_L$ is algebraic integer in $L$,$k_L=\mathcal O_L/p\mathcal O_L$ is the residue field,for a prime ideal $(p) \subset \mathbb Z$ inert in $L$,is the  natural induced map $Gal(L/\mathbb Q )\to Gal(k_L/\mathbb F_p)$ a isomorphism?I note the orders of the both sides are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, since it is a surjection between finite groups of the same order.

Comment: why is it surjective

Comment: @DanielXu Pick a generator $a+(p)$ of $O_L/(p)^\times$ and replace $O_L$ by $\Bbb{Z}[a]$. Let $f(x) = \prod_{j=1}^n (x-a_j)$ its minimal polynomial, where $a_j = g_j(a), g_j \in Gal(L/Q)$ and $ n = [L:Q] = [O_L/(p) / F_p]$. Since $\Bbb{Z}[x]/(f(x),p)$ is a field $f(x) \bmod p$ is irreducible, the reduction modulo $p$ is bijective on the $a_j$, sending them to different conjugates of $a+(p)$ thus to $a^{p^{e_j}}$ with $e_j \in 1 \ldots n$ all different. Thus $\sigma(a) \equiv a^p \bmod (p)$ for some $\sigma \in Gal(L/Q)$.